# awk to add one to column based on condition

Tags: awk

Trying to add a `awk` condition that will add one to `$2` if the sum of `$3` - `$2`is greater than one, The below has a syntax error on the `if` line. Thank you :).

**file**

```
2   21002880    21002881
17  3476163 3476186
11  108292759   108292760
2   218661210   218661265
2   21002865    21002866
```

**desired**

```
2   21002880    21002881
17  3476164 3476186
11  108292759   108292760
2   218661211   218661265
2   21002865    21002866
```

**awk**

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} {sum+=$3-$2}  # define FS, OFS, and sum
  if((sum > 1)) {  # condition check
     print $1,$2+1,$3  # print desired output
     next     # goto next line
  }
 }1' file.txt
```

Comment: SO is not the right place to ask for opinions, ("I think the below is close but there probably is a better way")

Comment: `{sum+=$3-$2}` ??  That is the short notation for `{sum= sum + $3-$2}` . Is that what you want to do ?

Comment: I updated the post with details.

Comment: @justaguy, Good that you have found it out, you could add it as an your own answer cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another short one:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '{$2+=($3-$2>1)}1' file
```

Output:

```
2       21002880        21002881
17      3476164 3476186
11      108292759       108292760
2       218661211       218661265
2       21002865        21002866
```

Answer (score 0):

I missed a `{` and needed  `sum=$3-$2`

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} {sum=$3-$2}  # define FS, OFS, and sum
 {
  if((sum > 1)) {  # condition check
    print $1,$2+1,$3  # print desired output
    next     # goto next line
 }
}1' file.txt
```

Comment: I don't think you need dbl-parens, just `if (sum > 1 ) { ...` should work fine. Dbl-parens is a shell scripting syntax. Glad you solved your problem.